# Time complexity of an algorithm in different cases

Tags: time-complexity

An old man trying to learn more and got stuck on this exercise in some old exam:

Specify the complexity, in Θ(.) Notation, of the **Test(n)** function, detailed below, in each of the following three cases:

1/ *n* is even.

2/ *n* is a perfect square, that is, there exists an integer i such that i² = n.

3/ *n* is a prime number.

**Function** Test( n : Integer) : Integer

Variable

```
i : Integer
```

Start

```
for i := 2 to n do

    if n mod i = 0 Return( i ) End-if

End-for
```

Return(n)

End

Comment: O(1), O(sqrt(n)), O(n). Can *you* reason why?

Comment: i can't  , would be helpful if you could give me the full reasoning,also don't i need to do both O() and Ω() beacause its Θ() . thanks in advance.

Comment: These are exact numbers in fact (that is tight bounds). You can see that for even `n` it will run at most twice (can you?) therefore it can be considered constant time. For perfect square it will run up to `i` satisfying `i^2=n` - that is a square root of `n`. For prime `n` there are no divisors other than `n` itself, so it will run up to `n` exactly.

Comment: Actually for even it will run exactly once

Comment: i understood the perfect square and the prime , thanks 
but with the even when you say twice do you mean when i = 2 at the start and when i = n ? i m not clear on that.
i wanted to ask , i m new to this and i only read about it no form of exercices yet so am i not supposed to prove these time complexities as i read them from example : f(n)∈o(g(n)) i have to prove something like f(n) <= c g(n) , c > 0 , ∀ n >= 0

Comment: For any even number it will run the for loop only once, as the first call to n mod i where i=2 will return 0. The fact that it runs only once for any even number, regardless of the even number's size, is why it's theta(1)

Comment: i think i get the gist of it , thanks everyone for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I think the comments have answered your general question, but a note about proving Big Theta time complexity:

To show f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n)), you don't necessarily have to prove f(n) ∈ O(g(n)) and f(n) ∈ Ω(g(n)) through the method you alluded to of showing there exists a constant `c` and an integer `n0` for which `for all n > n0 f(n) <  cg(n)`, and then finding another c and n0 for which `for all n > n0 f(n) > cg(n)`. Although this is perfectly valid and widely taught, there is an alternative, equally mathematically rigorous but generally much cleaner and more practical approach, which is just to show that:

```
0 < lim n-> \infty f(n) / g(n) < \infty
```

That is, f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n)) iff the limit as n goes to infinity of f(n) over g(n) is some constant.

If you showed only that

```
lim n-> \infty f(n) / g(n) < \infty
```

you would have shown that f(n) grows no faster than g(n): that is, that f(n) ∈ O(g(n)).

Similarly:

```
0 < lim n-> \infty f(n) / g(n)
```

implies that f(n) grows at least as fast as g(n): that f(n) ∈ Ω(g(n)). So together, they imply f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n))

Generally I think this is a lot less tedious than proofs of the form you mentioned, which involve actually finding c values and n0 values for the big O case, proving some needlessly particular statement involving those values, and then repeating the whole process for the Ω case, but that is just my opinion: whatever style works for you is good.